# How can I re-seal hearing aid batteries that have been accidentally unsealed?

Tags: packaging, batteries

Zinc-air hearing aid batteries come with a sticky tab on them to prevent air contact; once this tab is removed, the battery starts draining.  The instructions warn that "*thou shalt not removeth this tab until a few minutes before thine need of battery*".

Recently, my roommate's kids discovered that the tiny metal lumps with sticky things stuck to them were a much more enjoyable toy than the nice new expensive plastic monstrosity their father just gave them; long story short, about two months worth of hearing aid batteries are now unsealed (and hidden in crevices throughout the house, but I think I found them all).

Google searching has come up with mixed results regarding simply resealing them with Scotch tape, mostly suggesting that it won't work or that it will work but not enough to bother with.  However, these seem to be in the context of re-sealing while they're in use (i.e. prolonging the life of an active battery by re-sealing it when the hearing aids are turned off, rather than for any form of long-term storage).  I threw some tape on them anyway just on principle, but no clue how much if any effect it'll actually have.

How then could one reliably re-seal hearing aid batteries for long-term (well, one or two months) storage?  Does a simple patch of Scotch tape (or re-applying the original tab) actually work, or is this a lost cause?

Comment: Cellophane tape is fairly impermeable, so *if* you got to the cells soon enough, they should be OK. It's certainly worth trying a few to see if they last long enough to be useful.

Comment: If you have one of those "Food saver" things that sucks the air out of bags to preserve your food longer you could try that, but I don't know if it would work with anything other than the bags they give you for the machine, and that would be a huge waste for a little battery in one of those bags.

Comment: I've been using these batteries for years, and can't put them down because my cats grab them, so I know how you feel! Unfortunately, according to my audiologist, there's no safe way to store or re-seal them. They do start draining once the tab comes off, but that's not the only concern. Every other type of adhesive leaves sticky residue, which can damage the hearing aid. Anything the batteries have touched, like fabric, can also injure the device. Sorry I couldn't help! You can always stick some tape on your used batteries, and give those to the kids!

Comment: @SueSaddestFarewellTGOGL Swallowed batteries burn through a child's esophagus in just 2 hours, leading to surgery, months with feeding and breathing tubes, and even death. Your suggestion — Giving children a health hazard (swallowing tiny batteries) is ignorant and ***DISGUSTING***.

Comment: You cannot reverse the action of activating Zinc/Air hearing aid cells. It is a chemical reaction, once started continues to completion taking about a week.

Answer (score 1):

Candle wax is air tight, and will be easy to remove when you are ready to use the battery.
Just ensure that it isnt too hot when you submerge your battery in to the liquid wax.